# How to use grep to match exactly with space?

Tags: r

I have a list as following:

```
S = "Alicia Chang"
N=c("Alicia Chang", "Heather May", "Alicia Chang J")
```

I want to use grep to turn the first one only. How could I do it. When I use **grep(S, N)**, it return 3 of them. When I use **grep(^S$, N)**, it gave me error.

Comment: What's the pattern you're trying to match? If it's an exact string, just use == like @Heroka suggests.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `paste` to create the `pattern` for `grep`.

```
grep(paste0('^', S, '$'), N)
#[1] 1
```